# How should I load/change/activate scenes?

Tags: unity, c#, .net, scene, scenemanager

Scenes are confusing the hell out of me and I'm pretty sure they should be simple to understand.

When the game loads, only the current scene has a buildIndex != -1. In order give it a 'real' build index I need to load it by path or name (because there's no build index).

The scenes are ten game scenes, one title scene and one persistent scene (which has the player and the status bar with the score etc.).

Should I load a scene every time I change scene and then load additive afterwards or should I be using Set Active Scene?

All the scenes are ticked in the *Build Settings*.

[image: Build Settings]

I'm looking at the index with this:

```
private void Start()
{
    var sceneName = "Persistent";
    var sceneBeforeLoading = SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName);
    Debug.Log($"Scene {sceneBeforeLoading.name}, BI = {sceneBeforeLoading.buildIndex}");
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
    var sceneAfterLoading = SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName);
    Debug.Log($"Scene {sceneAfterLoading.name}, BI = {sceneBeforeLoading.buildIndex}");
}
```

Which outputs:

```
----------------------------------------------
Scene , BI = -1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Title:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/Title.cs:10)
----------------------------------------------
Scene Persistent, BI = 1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Title:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/Title.cs:13)
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you go to File > Build Settings, do you have any scenes selected (checkbox checked)  in the list of “Scenes in Build”?

Comment: [SceneManager.LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)

Comment: @Leon Aye, all ticked too.

Comment: @BanksySan when you say that only the current scene has a buildIndex !=1, where are you seeing all the other -1’s?

Comment: @Leon I added the code I used to show it above, along with the debug log.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have read the documentation or not on the matter but I would review  here [SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)

The build index is the numbers to the right on your pic of the build settings so you have a choice of 0-12 to load by index.

if loading by name you can load it

```
 SceneManager.LoadScene(scenename);
```

or by index

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneANumber);
```

you can also load the scene asynchronously using the index

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(0);
```

or by path if you have them bundled in a assetbundle of scenes

```
 private AssetBundle myLoadedAssetBundle;
private string[] scenePaths;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile("Assets/AssetBundles/scenes");
    scenePaths = myLoadedAssetBundle.GetAllScenePaths();
}

void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 30), "Change Scene"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Scene2 loading: " + scenePaths[0]);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scenePaths[0], LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope that helped to understand the scenes and build index better. Also noting: that every scene in your index != -1.